# Dynamically allocating and removing memory

Tags: python, memory-management, ctypes

Are things like `malloc` and `free` *possible* in Python?

```py
import ctypes

pointer = ctypes.malloc(10) # is this possible?
...
ctypes.free(pointer)
```

I know that it's a horrible idea to do this since Python is garbage collected, but I just want to know if this is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can call any C function exported from a DLL including the C runtime library DLL provided you provision the function correctly with `.argtypes` and `.restype`:

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('msvcrt')  # Windows C runtime

# void* malloc(size_t size);
dll.malloc.argtypes = ct.c_size_t,
dll.malloc.restype = ct.c_void_p
# void free(void* ptr);
dll.free.argtypes = ct.c_void_p,
dll.free.restype = None

ptr = dll.malloc(100)
dll.free(ptr)
```